# Взаимодействие клиента с сервером через сериализацию

Tags: java, java-ee

Всем привет. Я настраиваю взаимодействие клиента с сервером через сериализацию.

У меня есть класс-обертка в который я кладу название класса и метод, который мне нужно вызвать на сервере. перед отправкой на сервер он сериализуется, ну а там, соответственно, десериализуется.

Вопрос такой:

Некоторые методы на сервере должны возвращать мне какие-то объекты. Например объект класса `User`. На сервере лежит, предположим, `jar` файл из которого сервер и узнает о таком классе. А как клиент узнает об этом классе?

Ведь, я так понимаю, что неправильным подходом было бы продублировать и на клиенте и на сервере два файлика с этим классом?

Тогда, если на сервере этот класс изменится, то будет выдаваться ошибка при сериализации / десериализации?Или нет?

Answer (score 0):

По опыту скажу, что для этого не нужно использовать сериализацию, ибо как вы уже сами догадались придется дублировать поля и классы и даже директории в проекте. Лучше используете `JSON` или `xml`. Первый переделывает java объекты в javascript объект, а второй переделывает в xml и отправляет как строку. Самые простые, популярные и удобные способы

Comment: Ясно. Но если мне с сервера должен прийти List<User> в Json формате. На клиенте я преобразую Json обратно в List<User>. Ну а класс User мне откуда взять? Та же проблема вроде?

Comment: я для этого создавал на клиенте класс с нужными полями, чтоб передавать туда json и уже из этого класса спокойно получать все поля которые нужны. В общем надо будет написать миникласс User со всем необходимым (Логин, пароль, сообщение, дата например)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Как я понимаю, если я получаю от сервера List<User> в Json  формате, то чтобы его нормально преобразовать в то, что мне нужно, я должен на клиенте создать класс User с такими же полями как у User-а на сервере?

Comment: да, но не обязательно. Если хотите то можно самому обработать json как обычную строку и достать всю нужную информацию, но это выглядит как-то костыльно + будут баги, ведь не всегда пользователем будет отправляться идеальная строка, а вы не все сможете учесть, в отличии от библиотечных решений